# How to exclude cases in php regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to capture specific data where a colon exists. I have tried this:

```
preg_match_all("/^(.+):(.+)/im", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

on this input data

```
last_name, first_name
bjorge philip: hello world    
bjorge:world
kardashian, kim
some http://hi.com ok
jim https://hey.com yes
same http://www.vim.com:2018 why
it's about 20/08/2018 1:23 pm
time is 01:20:24 now
capture my name : my name is micky mouse
mercury, freddie
I need to be:
captured
  capture me :    
 if you can
 where is  : freddie
freddie is not:
 home
```

I need to capture the `bjorge philip: hello world`, `bjorge:world`, `I need to be: captured`, `capture me :     if you can`, `where is  : freddie`, `freddie is not: home` and `capture my name : my name is micky mouse` lines and exclude any line that contains either time or URL

Comment: in your example `colon space` would work

Comment: Make your life easier and iterate over each line separately rather than trying to write a multi-line regex.

Comment: @nogad that space is optional. sorry I edited my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$input_lines="last_name, first_name
bjorge philip: hello world    
bjorge:world
kardashian, kim
some http://hi.com ok
jim https://hey.com yes
same http://www.vim.com:2018 why
it's about 20/08/2018 1:23 pm
time is 01:20:24 now
capture my name : my name is micky mouse
mercury, freddie
I need to be:
captured
  capture me :    
 if you can
 where is  : freddie
freddie is not:
 home ";

preg_match_all("/^|\n(?![^:]*$|.*?https?:|.*\d:\d+)(.*?:\s*\r?\n.*|.*?:\s?.+)/",$input_lines,$output_array);
// \r? can be omitted from regex depending on system

foreach($output_array[0] as $output){
    echo $output,"<br>";
}
```

Regex pattern breakdown:

```
^|\n                     #start string from beginning of $input_lines or after any newline
    (?!                  #begin negative lookahead group
        [^:]*$           #ignore lines with no colon
        |                #OR
        .*?https?:       #ignore lines with http: or https:
        |                #OR
        .*\d:\d          #ignore lines with digit colon digit
    )                    #end negative lookahead group
    (                    #begin capture group
        .*?:\s*\r?\n.*   #capture 2 lines if 1st line has a colon then 0 or more
                         # spaces with no non-white characters before the newline
        |                #OR
        .*?:\s?.+        #capture 1 line when it contains a colon followed by
                         # 0 or 1 space then 1 or more non-white characters
    )                    #end capture group
```

This returns:

```
bjorge philip: hello world 
bjorge:world 
capture my name : my name is micky mouse 
I need to be: captured 
capture me : if you can 
where is : freddie 
freddie is not: home
```

I have spent a considerable amount of time writing this solution for you.  If there are no further extensions to the sample set, I hope it earns your tick of approval.

Comment: having a space or not is optional so I can't rely on that as the trigger. I edited my example

Comment: that's awesome @mickmackusa. what would you add in there if the line ends with a colon. ie `hello world: `?

Comment: or a way to capture the following line

Comment: @Kal Please update your question and I'll have another crack at it with your newest sample extension.

Comment: @Kal new answer provided.